# how to insert a new line with text before the match

Tags: parsing, awk, insertion

I was able to extract these lines from a text file

```
TBL Papers
Papers_ShortName "TPJ341861"
Papers_Name "BANK    240314 341861    "
MMInstrumentType P "Discounted Paper"
```

but wanted to insert a new line( text before the match TBL Papers). see expected output

```
ACTION "INS"
TBL Papers
Papers_ShortName "TPJ341861"
Papers_Name "BANK    240314 341861    "
MMInstrumentType P "Discounted Paper"
```

How do I do that ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/TBL Papers/ {$0="ACTION \"INS\"" RS$0}8' file
ACTION "INS"
TBL Papers
Papers_ShortName "TPJ341861"
Papers_Name "BANK    240314 341861    "
MMInstrumentType P "Discounted Paper"
```

This code will add a line above pattern `TBL Papers` and then print everything out.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/TBL Papers/{ print "ACTION \"INS\"" } 1' file
```